# Excel - Multiply text and sort in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I work with multiple keywords and target local cities in a county.  Many times I will be targeting 50 - 100 keywords for 20-50 cities.  I need these keywords listed a certain way.

For example:  If I have 5 keywords targeting 5 cities, I would need a list of 25 total keywords in one excel column. It just depends on my project how many keywords I will be using and how many cities I will target.

So if I have a list of:

```
keyword1
keyword2
keyword3
keyword4    
keyword5
```

Since I would be targeting 5 cities, each keyword would need to be multiplied by 5.

Need to be able to add that list to excel and have it create a list like this I can copy out:

```
keyword1    
keyword1    
keyword1    
keyword1    
keyword1    
keyword2    
keyword2    
keyword2    
keyword2    
keyword2    
keyword3    
keyword3    
keyword3    
keyword3    
keyword3    
keyword4    
keyword4   
keyword4    
keyword4    
keyword4    
keyword5    
keyword5    
keyword5    
keyword5    
keyword5
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you open to VBA?

Comment: Have you tried or thought of pivot table for such an application. What version of Excel You have.

Comment: `=INDEX(A:A,QUOTIENT(ROW(1:1)-1,5)+1)`

Comment: Screenshot showing concept of City vs Keywords can be viewed [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cc1zxx56mas5u4/ice_screenshot_20160525-231455.png?dl=0)

Comment: @ScottCraner now, who's not posting answers =P

Comment: @findwindow you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula in the first row where you want to start your list and copy down.

```
=INDEX(A:A,QUOTIENT(ROW(1:1)-1,5)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any added benefit to using `quotient(a,b)` vs `int(a/b)`?

Comment: Not that I am aware, I use it to make me look smart. @gtwebb