# Vlookup with Column as variable

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to use vlookup, and the column number as a variable which is dependent on users input.

```
Dim MONTH As Variant
MONTH = InputBox("month number ex: Apr=4")

Range("F7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],C[8]:C[22],3+MONTH,FALSE),0)"
```

The function can run through but the column doesn't really take in user's input. So I am actually searching "3+MONTH"th column.

Does anyone know how to properly solve it so i can really take user's input into the formula?

Comment: Try `"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],C[8]:C[22]," & 3+MONTH & ",FALSE),0)"` Edit: in before Scott tells me to post answer =P

Comment: @findwindow Y U NO post an answer? ;o)

Comment: @Mat'sMug ugh, should have included you on the `in before Scott` too XD Edit: CUZ I AM WAITING FOR YOOOU TO DOOO EEET

Comment: @findwindow Why? why does that work while the other does not?

Comment: See? This is why I want one of you to do it so I can troll instead =P

Comment: As an side, y'all need to upvote [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443722/excel-multiply-text-and-sort-in-one-column#37443722) because the logic is simply brilliant.

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't know how to explain it. Because, when you enclose something in quotes, it's taken as text. But it's a variable so you place it outside the quotes and concatenate it with `&`.

Comment: @findwindow good, now put all that in an answer.

Comment: sorry guys this is literally my first time writing VBA, most of the project is finished my recording my action.

Comment: @ScottCraner YOUU DOO EEEET

Comment: @PingHungWu you're doing just fine~ Edit: also tell Scott to post answer. Edit2: or tell Mat.

Comment: with that.. " & 3 +MONTH &" works! But I still don't quite understand how it works. --------------- i understand it now, thanks!

Comment: Aha! I can't explain it properly. Clearly I can't answer.

Comment: @findwindow thank you, what you just commented is very clear.

Comment: Could this just use a lookup in [both directions](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-perform-a-twoway-lookup-in-excel-2013.html) `=index(.,match,match)` what else is the macro doing?

Comment: Wow, only @gtwebb upvoted that link. I hate the rest of you.

Answer (score 3):

```
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],C[8]:C[22],3+MONTH,FALSE),0)"
```

That's a *string literal*; you need to "chop it" and *insert* your variable in there.

Use the *string concatenation operator* (`&`) to put the pieces together

```
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],C[8]:C[22]," & 3+MONTH & ",FALSE),0)"
```

Comment: @findwindow you bet!

Comment: Well, gonna troll it by not creating CR account. Booyah.

Comment: @findwindow anything to get you to be here less, jk =P

Comment: @findwindow FWIW, I'm not giving up. You'll end up reviewing VBA on [codereview.se] one way or another. Answering lazy dupes on SO is one thing, reviewing working code where the OP put their best coding effort and says "is there anything I can improve?" is *something else* - and we're a fun bunch too. [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) is waiting for you =)

Comment: @findwindow pffft, you'll need a better reason; some of the top reviewers were exactly in your shoes ("but I'm not qualified! I suck! I know nothing! I'm the Jon Snow of VBA!") a few months ago! and you learn much more, and faster, by reviewing working code, and reading other people's reviews =)