# Transpose column with duplicates to unique columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wonder if it's possible to transpose column with grouped duplicate fields, like for example:

```
+---------+------+
| field_1 | 1    |
| field_2 | 2    |
| field_3 | 3    |
| field_4 | 4    |
| field_1 | 5    |
| field_2 | 6    |
| field_3 | 7    |
| field_4 | 8    |
| field_1 | 9    |
| field_2 | 10   |
| field_3 | 11   |
| field_4 | 12   |
+---------+------+
```

to unique columns, like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | 2       | 3       | 4       |
| 5       | 6       | 7       | 8       |
| 9       | 10      | 11      | 12      |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Is this possible without scripting?

Comment: Without "scripting" (for example using [tag:vba]) your question might be better asked at the sistersite [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/search?q=excel+transpose+).

Comment: @slackmuggle quite common to do things in excel without scripting.  There is a whole tag for just that `excel-formula`.  Which should be added.

Comment: @ForwardEd this may very well be but my understanding is that this would be a better fit at superuser.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter the formula below in E3 (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter) then fill down and then across.

```
=OFFSET($C$1,LARGE((ROW($B$2:$B$13)-1)*($B$2:$B$13=E$2),ROW()-2),0) & ""
```

[image]

Values are not in the listed order but are at least in the correct column.

Will try to explain:

- All of the values we want for each of the distinct "field" values are offset by some "x" number of rows from C1
- Taking "field_1" as an example `(ROW($B$2:$B$13)-1)*($B$2:$B$13=E$2)` will return an array of row numbers multiplied by either 1 (TRUE) or zero (FALSE) depending on whether the "B" cell value matches "field_1" (from E2). The `-1` is an adjustment because we're starting on row 2.  The returned array looks like:

  [1,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,9,0,0,0]
- Given that array, we need to find some way to get at the non-zero values one by one: we can use LARGE() to do that, incrementing the second argument to LARGE using `ROW()-2` (-2 because we want that second argument to begin at 1 and the formula is being entered in row 3).  This gives us an ordered array of values:

  [9,5,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
- We pass this ordered array as the "row offset" argument to OFFSET(), counting  down from C2: all non-zero values give us the value we want from Col C, whereas all the zero values just return C2 (which is empty, and would show as `0` without that last `& ""`
- All cell references in the formula use $ where needed so it adjusts as needed on dragging to fill down/across

Comment: Damn you for answering while I was tidying up! Nice option!  I did the same thing you did in terms of display order the first run through.  I think if you use SMALL instead of LARGE, you will preserve the vertical order in which the information appears.  With large you are just working from the bottom up.

Comment: DOH I forgot you will l have all those false 0 with small. Ran into that problem yesterday!  Could you add `COUNT($B$2:$B$13<>E$2)` to your `ROW()-2` to skip all the 0s if you went with the SMALL version of your formula?

Comment: @ForwardEd - I did look into replacing the zeros but that just added more complexity which I thought it could do without...

Comment: I knew I needed `row` somehow but couldn't get it to work :/ Can you post formula as text instead of picture so I can copy/paste please?

Comment: Awwwwwwwwwww you didn't have to <333 (i was just kidding XD)

Comment: Ahahahah nice. I am half way into studying it now^^ Edit: you don't explain why data needs to start on `B2` but I figured it out =P Edit2: I know SO wants answers explained but I don't. Better to study it on my own ^_^;

Comment: Data starts on B2 because that's where the data is ?

Comment: Oh, you're including the border XD Actually, I realized you can simply remove/change the math depending on location ^_^;

Answer (score 1):

This only gets you so far. You still need to remove duplicates. In `D2`:

```
=INDEX($B1:$B$12,MATCH(D$1,$A1:$A$12,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Couldn't get @scottcraner [brilliance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443722/excel-multiply-text-and-sort-in-one-column#37443722) to work XD Edit: I think I need `sumproduct` oh well, time to go home.

Comment: I ended by using `offset` from B1 to B4: `=OFFSET($B1;(ROW()-1)*3;0)`, then autofill down

Comment: @findwindow And here I was about to give you a +1 for such a compact and efficient formula!

Comment: @findwindow Since you were saying you have a hard time wrapping your head around SUMPRODUCT the other day, I thought you might want to read [the later half of the answer posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460115/i-need-to-get-a-column-of-data-that-equals-a-specific-thing-into-an-array/37460811?noredirect=1#comment62430516_37460811).

Comment: Dude, what did we say about not enough screenshots/words XD

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to Tim's but avoids the CSE part and internalizes it within the AGGREGATE function.  Also believe it will preserve the vertical order in which the element in B occurs (not tested though).

In D1 use the following formula and copy right to get your unique list of headers.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$12,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C1:C1,$A$1:$A$12),0,0),0))
```

Then in D2 use the following to pull your information from column B.  It can be copied to the right and down.  When an item is not found it will display not found.  you can change this to "" if you prefer.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$12)/($A$1:$A$12=D$1),ROW(1:1))),"Not found")
```

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of concept]

Note on OFFSET

OFFSET is a volatile function meaning that it will recalculate anytime anything on the worksheet changes, not just the cells it works with.  As such if you are only using it a couple of times, no big deal.  However if you are using it repeatedly you may experience a slow down with your worksheet.